# WAFStaleDataException from Java SDK but the same token works with CLI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-waf

My code first gets the change token to be used

`final AWSWAFRegional waf = AWSWAFRegionalClientBuilder.defaultClient();
final String changeToken = waf.getChangeToken(new GetChangeTokenRequest()).toString();`

It then uses the token to update IPSet

`UpdateIPSetRequest updateIPSetRequest = new UpdateIPSetRequest();
updateIPSetRequest.setChangeToken(changeToken);
waf.updateIPSet(updateIPSetRequest);`

The problem is, when I run the function it returns

`com.amazonaws.services.waf.model.WAFStaleDataException: The input token is no longer current. (Service: AWSWAFRegional; Status Code: 400; Error Code: WAFStaleDataException;`

After that when I use the same token from AWS CLI it works but the code was unable to use it as it threw WAFStaleDataException. What is the resolution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this statement

```
final String changeToken = waf.getChangeToken(new GetChangeTokenRequest()).toString();
```

use of **toString()** results changeToken to be of the form {ChangeToken: "xxxxxx"} where "xxxxxx" is the required change token, should have used

```
final String changeToken = waf.getChangeToken(new GetChangeTokenRequest()).getChangeToken();
```